# How Solr stores a fieldtype with 2 or more filters that returns the same value?

Tags: solr, fieldtype

I have a fieldtype in my schema like this:

```
<fieldType name="cleanquery" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern=" " replacement="-"/>
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="/" replacement="-"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When I index this value: "Grand Suite", the steps for this fieldType are these:

```
KT -> Grand Suite
LCF -> grand suite
ASCIIFF -> grand suite
PRF -> grand-suite
PRF -> grand-suite
```

As you can see, the steps 2 and 3, 4 and 5 returns the same values. How Solr stores internally these steps? It saves two times the same value or, if the value is identical, it stores just one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr stores the value that is output by the last filter in your analyzer chain, in this case `grand-suite`. What you are seeing here is the progression of how the value you have supplied is transformed by the various analyzers you have defined for the field.

Comment: But if I search for "grand suite", I got a match. If Solr stores only the last output, how this match occurs?

Comment: Are you querying directly against this field `cleanquery` or are you searches against another field that is performing additional or alternate analysis on the values at query time?

Comment: Directly against cleanquery. I said this based in solr's analysis page from admin menu.

Comment: OK. I set this up locally. Since you are using the analysis page in the menu, you can see that the same analyzers are being applied at query time as at index time and the first pattern replace filter is replacing the space with a hyphen in your query term and that is where the match is happening (it should be highlighted on the left side).